# Spring security logout call

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, logout

I'm trying to setup Spring Security + mvc using Java config, but for some reason it's not working, I getting a 404 error.

In my implemented WebApplicationInitializer class I register security filter next way

```
 @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
...
       FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        securityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
..
```

Listing of SecurityContext

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
//        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
//        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/profile/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error")
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .permitAll()
//                .and()
//                    .logout()
//                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
//                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
//                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
     }
}
```

For the logoutUrl I've tried all combinations with no luck...
When i'm trying to use this link in my jsp page

```
<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />
```

I'm getting 404 not found exception.

I've spent whole day trying to make it work. Is anyone have an ideas how to solve this issue?

PS If I'll set logoutUrl to "/logout" for example, should I make a contoller to handle this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logOut mechanizm doesn't work... Is it means that your logIn mechanizm works right? 
In this case, realy, try to handle your '/logOut' url:

```
public LogInController{
...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logOut(ModelMap model) {

    //Redirect to your start page (mapping the url '/welcome' for example)
    return "redirect:welcome";
    }
...
}
```

If not, check whether you have added your Security configuration file to your 'onStartup' method:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {


 AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        //adding your main config class 
        rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        //adding your security config class
        rootContext.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);
...

}
```

Then you can try add after http. in 'configure' method this (if you don't use csrf tokens till authorization):

```
 csrf().disable()
```

And check other beans:

```
@Bean
public ProviderManager providerManager() {
    List<AuthenticationProvider> list = new ArrayList<AuthenticationProvider>();
    list.add(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    return new ProviderManager(list);
}

//If you use this filter (I think so, because you've defined 'username' and 'password' in
'configure' method)
@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter filter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(providerManager());
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: Adding csrf().disable() solved the issue!!!
I have no idea why it was enabled by default.

Comment: I read that it is a Spring Java Configuration characteristic only (no XML)